# get the bounds (min max sub-aggregation) of top_hits query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using an elasticsearch query to get the N oldests documents in an index. then using programmatic way to get min and max dates of the result.

Actual query I'm using is something like

```json
### sorted search limited to N result
POST _search?filter_path=hits.total,hits.hits._source.date
{
  "_source": [ "date" ],
  "size": 3,
  "sort": { "date": "asc" },
  "query": { "bool": { "filter": { "term": { "queue.name": "messages.in.dlq" }}}
}


{
  "hits": {
    "total": 254,
    "hits": [
      { "_source": { "date": "2023-10-31T10:51:32.185+0100" } },
      { "_source": { "date": "2023-10-31T11:13:15.919+0100" } },
      { "_source": { "date": "2023-10-31T14:39:37.559+0100" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to get only min and max date of this result directly from elasticsearch. Thus I tried aggregations :

```json
### aggregated search
POST errormessages-search/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.value_as_string
{
  "_source": [ "date" ],
  "size": 3,
  "sort": { "date": "asc" },
  "query": { "term": { "queue.name": "messages.in.dlq" }},
  "aggs": {
    "date_min": { "min": { "field": "date" }},
    "date_max": { "max": { "field": "date" }}
  }
}

{
  "aggregations": {
    "date_min": { "value_as_string": "2023-10-31T09:51:32.185Z" },
    "date_max": { "value_as_string": "2024-01-08T09:03:10.565Z" } //!\\ overall date_max not the oldest 3
  }
}
```

But as you can see the date_max is taken overall document rather than just the 3 oldest one.

I also tried using top_hits, but it fails with and error of sub-aggregation not allowed for top_hits.

```json
### top_hits then min max aggregation
POST _search?filter_path=aggregations.oldest_agg.aggregations
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": { "bool": { "filter": {"term": { "queue.name": "messages.in.dlq" }}}},
  "aggs": {
    "oldest_agg": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 3,
        "sort": { "date": "asc" }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "date_min": { "min": { "field": "date" }},
        "date_max": { "max": { "field": "date" }}
      }
    }
  }
}


{
  "error": {
    "type": "aggregation_initialization_exception",
    "reason": "Aggregator [oldest_agg] of type [top_hits] cannot accept sub-aggregations"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Is there a way to have what I want with aggregations? I would prefer to let elasticsearch compute those min and max, because I'll need thousands oldest documents later on.

==[EDIT 2024-01-11 21:40:44]==
following @LeBigCat advice I tried the sampler parent aggregation, but result are inconsistant, 18 docs are get in sampler (seems some random within each shard). not taking sort into account.

```json
### sampler aggregation
GET errormessages-search/_search?filter_path=**.date,**.doc_count,**.date_*.value_as_string
{
  "_source": [ "date" ],
  "size": 3,
  "sort": { "date": "asc" },
  "query": { "bool": { "filter": { "term": { "queue.name": "messages.in.dlq" }}}},
  "aggs": {
    "sample": {
      "sampler": {
        "shard_size": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "date_min": { "min": { "field": "date" }},
        "date_max": { "max": { "field": "date" }}
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      { "_source": { "date": "2024-01-02T20:57:22.812+0100" } },
      { "_source": { "date": "2024-01-02T20:57:22.812+0100" } },
      { "_source": { "date": "2024-01-02T20:57:22.901+0100" } }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "sample": {
      "doc_count": 18,
      "date_min": { "value_as_string": "2024-01-02T19:57:22.812Z" },
      "date_max": { "value_as_string": "2024-01-03T01:22:02.233Z" }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: size only control the number of returned documents. Agregation match with the query.

you are looking for Sample Aggregation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html

Comment: thank you for the hint, but unfortunately it doesn't work, the sample seems to distribute the query amoung the shards, not taking into account any sort. see edit for details